# Turn CustomErrors off and on quickly for production and development

Tags: asp.net, web-services, exception, custom-error-pages, custom-errors

I develop a lot of ASP.NET web forms. During testing, I have customErrors off, then I have a ResponseRedirect custom error for when I move the form into production.

I'm wondering if I can simplify my development by just changing a setting value to accomplish this.

What I would like is to just change my Properties.Settings.Default.TestMode value from **developer** to **production** and have this turn on the customError.

So I was thinking my Global.asax.cs code could look like:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (Properties.Settings.Default.TestMode == "production") {
    Server.ClearError();
    Response.Redirect("errorpage.htm");
  } 
  else {
    // Not sure what it would do here. Nothing?
  }
}
```

But then I'm not sure what would go in my Web.config file.
CustomErrors is shown below.

```
<!--<customErrors mode="Off" />-->
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.htm" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect"/>
```

Right now I just comment out/in what I need to to make the change. I feel like I do this all the time and it would be great to just have the TestMode setting that I've created do all the work.

Comment: Have you ever tried setting the customErrors mode to RemoteOnly? As I'm sure you're aware, that enables custom errors for (as the name implies) remote connections, but if you're testing from the local server/machine, then you would bypass custom errors.

Comment: I actually did come upon this solution, but the reason I didn't like it is because I need to test on the remote system for many features to work, so I barely test on my local machine past a certain point.

One example is sending out emails...my machine is blocked from doing so on our network, whereas the remote test server is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look into **Web.Config Transformation**. It allows you to set specific settings for development and production independently.

Here is a good walk through from Microsoft: [How to: Transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)